# what happens when Amazon is backuping RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using RDS(MySQL) with one of my Laravel project. but one question is floating in my mind that what happens to the project when amazon is creating a backup of the rds instance. Is it:

- Freeze the project
- The project throws an exception
- working Normal

Comment: I don't know, but I would imagine that RDS is just going to use whatever backup methods MySQL already exposes.  You can read about those [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/backup-types.html).  One question is what happens if, during a backup, new data comes in or other DML is taking place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single instance RDS the database I/O may be suspended for a few seconds while the snapshot is created. During this period all requests to the database will be paused, but they will be resumed after the snapshot is created.

So if you have a webapp, requests received during the I/O suspension period will be served slower then usually.

You can mitigate this with a [multi-AZ](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/) RDS deployment, because in case of multi-AZ, the snapshot is taken from the standby instance. So there is no I/O suspension on the master instance.

Relevant documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html#USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.BackupWindow

Answer (score 1):

Your application will continue to work normally during backups. Since AWS RDS [uses volume snapshots](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/backup/) the MySQL service is running without any interruption. This is how manual snapshots or point-in-time recovery works as well.

Comment: The link you attached doesn't say that MySQL service is running without any interruption. By default, MySQL locks all tables while creating a backup

Comment: The key takeaway from the product page is that it uses "storage volume snapshot of your DB instance, backing up the entire DB instance". This means that RDS backup works at a lower (volume) level. When it comes to point-in-time restore, RDS will restore the data from the snapshot and then re-do MySQL logs up to the specified point-in-time. This can happen because RDS backup covers the entire instance, including binary logs.